# Keras Lambda layer runs twice even though called once

Tags: python, keras

I define a Lambda layer. In the layer, I split a feature map into patches,  flatten each patch into a one-dimensional vector and calculate cosine distance of each two vector.

The problem is, I call the Lambda layer just once, but it runs twice (the evidence is: all print in the layer run twice).

Here is the code:

```py
def MPSM_model(input_size):
    rfam_model = RFAM_model(input_size)
    rfam_output = rfam_model.output
    print(np.array(rfam_output).shape)
 

    similarity = Lambda(mpsm_process)(rfam_output)


    model = Model(inputs=rfam_model.input, outputs=similarity, name='MPSM_model')
    return model

def mpsm_process(rfam_output):
    batch_size = 16
    # batch_size = U_concat.shape[0]

    i_low = rfam_output[0]
    f_low = rfam_output[1]
    i_mid = rfam_output[2]
    f_mid = rfam_output[3]
    i_high = rfam_output[4]
    f_high = rfam_output[5]

    U_low = i_low + f_low
    print("low shape: " + str(U_low.shape))
    U_mid = i_mid + f_mid
    print("mid shape: " + str(U_mid.shape))
    U_high = i_high + f_high
    print("high shape: " + str(U_high.shape))


    H_low = int(U_low.shape[1])
    W_low = int(U_low.shape[2])
    
    H_mid = int(U_mid.shape[1])
    W_mid = int(U_mid.shape[2])

    H_high = int(U_high.shape[1])
    W_high = int(U_high.shape[2])

    U_low = U_low[:, ::(H_low//H_high), ::(W_low//W_high), :]
    U_mid = U_mid[:, ::(H_mid//H_high), ::(W_mid//W_high), :]

    U_low = U_low[:, :H_high, :W_high, :]
    U_mid = U_mid[:, :H_high, :W_high, :]

    U_concat = concatenate([U_low, U_mid, U_high], name='U_concat')

    H_U = int(U_concat.shape[1])
    W_U = int(U_concat.shape[2])

    U_concat = U_concat[:, :(H_U - H_U % 5), :(W_U - W_U % 5), :]
    print("concat shape: " + str(U_concat.shape))

    cube_size = H_U // 5
    tensor_map = [[[0 for t in range(5)] for i in range(5)] for j in range(batch_size)]
    print(np.array(tensor_map).shape)

    for b in range(batch_size):
        one_batch = U_concat[b]
        # print(one_batch.shape)
        for h in range(5):
            for w in range(5):
                cur_tensor = one_batch[h*cube_size : (h+1)*cube_size, w*cube_size : (w+1)*cube_size, :]
                # print(cur_tensor.shape)
                reshape_tensor = Flatten()(cur_tensor)
                reshape_tensor = reshape_tensor[np.newaxis, :, :]
                reshape_tensor = Flatten()(reshape_tensor)
                # print(reshape_tensor.shape)
                tensor_map[b][h][w] = reshape_tensor
                # print(np.array(tensor_map).shape)
    
    similarity_map = [[[0 for t in range(25)] for i in range(25)] for j in range(batch_size)]

    id_map = [  [0,1,2,3,4], 
                [5,6,7,8,9],
                [10,11,12,13,14],
                [15,16,17,18,19],
                [20,21,22,23,24]    ]

    for b in range(batch_size):
        for h in range(5):
            for w in range(5):
                tensor_1 = tensor_map[b][h][w]
                id_1 = id_map[h][w]

                for m in range(5):
                    for n in range(5):
                        tensor_2 = tensor_map[b][m][n]
                        id_2 = id_map[m][n]

                        cos_value = cosine(tensor_1, tensor_2)

                        # print(cos_value.shape)

                        similarity_map[b][id_1][id_2] = cos_value
                        similarity_map[b][id_2][id_1] = cos_value
    
    similarity_map = tf.convert_to_tensor(similarity_map)
    similarity = K.reshape(similarity_map, (similarity_map.shape[0], similarity_map.shape[1], similarity_map.shape[2], similarity_map.shape[3]))
    print(similarity.shape)

    return similarity
```

Comment: Why do you consider this being a problem? The function has to be called twice, once to make the train function, and another to make the validation/predict function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, I can't fully understand what you mean. During training, use model.train_ on_ Batch. When verifying, use model.test_ on_ Batch. Aren't these two independent processes? My understanding is that when the above two functions are called, they will pass through the lambda layer once

Comment: No, because when the model is created, always two functions are needed internally, one for training, and another for testing/prediction, so the graph has to be built twice, since layers might behave differently between train and test.

Comment: So this is a normal phenomenon. Thank you very much!